# Type 'MutableRefObject<null>' is missing the following properties from type 'Element'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-intersection-observer

I'd like to use intersection observer in my React TS project.

(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intersection-observer)

**At one point I cannot set the root:**

```
const root = useRef(null);

const { ref, inView, entry } = useInView({
     root: root,
     threshold: 0,
     onChange: () => console.log(inView)
});
```

**At this point the root option gives this error:**

```
Type 'MutableRefObject<null>' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': attributes, classList, className, clientHeight, and 164 more.ts(2740)
```

Can I set the root with ref?

Comment: Can you try `const root = useRef<Element | null>(null);`? Don't forget to set ref to Element and check if it's set when you use it.

Comment: Basically same: Type 'MutableRefObject<null>' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': attributes, classList, className, clientHeight, and 164 more.ts(2740)

Answer (score 0):

```
const rootRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

const { ref, inView } = useInView({
  root: rootRef.current,
  rootMargin: "0px",
});
```

The `current` property is used to access or modify the mutable value or object.